# how to display error information onto another page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

**how to display error onto another page?**

I have a form under user folder

And in another place, my_account folder, i render the form from user folder inside the index page of my_account. so that i can reuse the form,to allow user to update their user information.

So when user click update, update method in UserController will be invoked.

My question is, if faild to update user object, how can i display error message on to my_account index page, and still have the field highlight, and error message??
e.g invalid format of email address

```
User
    -- new.html.erb
    -- _form

my_account
    -- index.html.erb
```

I tried to do following, but not sure how can i print the "error" in my_account page:

```
// try to update user information

// if failed, redirect to my account page
  format.html { redirect_to my_account_path, :error => @user.errors }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the errors to be set on the user object.  This is used by form helper to display error messages when calling <%= f.error_messages %> inside your <% form_for %> block.

The Rails best-practice is to call **render** here, not **redirect**, so that we ensure we pass the @user object that has *errors* properly assigned.

To render the action, you can simply call:

```
 if !@user.save
   render :action => '../my_account/index'
 end
```

This should easily solve your problem; just make sure to have all of your @member-variables set that the *index.html.erb* view expects.

Comment: Hi ghayes, i got error Missing template ../my_account/index with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths.    do i need to do anything in the routes config?

Comment: change the path to be "/my_account/index" ... and it is working for me....great thx..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about it but might work for you.

In update method of user_controller when you get any error just redirect to the index page of my_account and pass the error details with it to be displayed on index page. ie.:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  ##  update process and if fails
  redirect_to :action=> 'index', :status=>:unprocessable_entity, :error=>@user.errors
end
```

Comment: hmm..it doesn`t work... how can i get the error message then?

Comment: if i keep this  ":status=>:unprocessable_entity", i will have a blank page, saying it is redirecting....

Comment: the code above is not tested you may need to update it to fit in your situation.

Comment: yes... i know... and i try to.... but the problem is, how can i read the error message?.. i remove the satus. the redirect is working again.. but not sure how can i read the error message and print it onto page